# Is swfobject.js still needed in html5 for swf files?

Tags: html, flash, swfobject

I developed an online training course 5 years ago that had many `swf` files on many pages. This was XHTML. I needed the *swfobjwct.js* file, plus I needed MANY lines of code for the `swf` to play. I did not write this code, Dreamweaver did on insert.

So, now I'm being asked to update this training course. I have converted each html file to html5. I've noticed that I can use this one simple line of code:

```
embed src="swf/m02-02.swf" width="91px" height="20px"/
```

I don't seem to need anything else. All old code that used to be needed for this swf to play has been stripped out.

I've tested it a few places and the file works. I had a few people test it on their platform and it also works.

Is this all I need nowadays to play an `swf` file?

I don't want to change the remaining 200 files if for some reason this isn't correct.

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers understand `<embed>` -- most browsers have supported it for years, but HTML5 made it official -- and yes, you can use it to embed a SWF to your page directly without SWFObject. However, if the browser does not have Flash Player installed (and many don't nowadays), the learner will only see whatever "unable to load content" message that particular browser provides.

SWFObject provides extra features, namely detection of Flash support, enabling you to provide fallback content if Flash is not available.

Adobe Dreamweaver spit out some hairy code back in the day, so I'd recommend continuing to use SWFObject but replacing Adobe's bloated code with some cleaner code of your own. There are simple examples for SWFObject at http://learnswfobject.com/the-basics/dynamic-publishing/index.html

Regardless, if you change your code, be sure to test in all major browsers, including IE9-11.

Comment: Thank you thank you. This is exactly what I needed to hear.

Comment: you can add <a> or whatever tag to inform and download flash just before </object> i had issues with ExternalInterdace.AddCallback with swfobject  (i was working local though) so i hate it. and no need to have another js file included in my pages. click to activate days long gone.